# Adding Control to Gridview Cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic-controls, rowdatabound

I want to add a button on GridView cell on certain condition.
I did the following in RowDatabound event

```
if( i==0)
{
   Button btn= new Button();
   btn.Text = "view more";        
   e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

When this executes, the text in the cell which is bound is lost and only the button appears.
I need to have the button along with the cell text present already.

Can anyone please help me doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a workaround, check if it helps you:

You can convert your existing BoundColumn to `Linkbuton` if it is feasible with your requirement.

```
if( i==0)
{
    LinkButton lnkbtn = new LinkButton();
    lnkbtn.Text = e.Row.Cells[7].Text;
   // Create a command button and link it to your id    
   // lnkbtn.CommandArgument = e.Row.Cells[0].Text; --Your Id 
   // lnkbtn.CommandName = "NumClick";
   // btn.Text = "view more";        
    e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(lnkbtn);
}
```

Comment: Is it Possible to retain the text and add the control as well?

Comment: @SandraDsouza Can you elaborate a little more about retaining text and control ?

Comment: I want to have linkbutton text as "view More". But when I do that the text in the cell[7] is lost. I want to have that text as well

Comment: @Sandra  Please check updated answer, As per my understanding you can create a command button as in comments above or if you want two buttons then, Create those directly on aspx page and make those `viewmore` button only for selected rows at `RowDatabound` event.

Answer (score 6):

When you add a control into the cell it trumps the text in the cell and only wants to display the control(s).

You can however have both the text and the button while keeping them separate. To do this you need to add another control in the form of a label:

```
Label myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Text = e.Row.Cells[7].Text; //might want to add a space on the end of the Text
e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(myLabel);

LinkButton myLinkButton = new LinkButton();
myLinkButton.Text = "view more";
e.Row.Cells[7].Controls.Add(myLinkButton);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to recreate all dynamic controls on every postback. But `RowDataBound`  is executed only if the grid gets databound. So this is not the right approach.

If this is just a single button you should add it declaratively to the aspx in a `TemplateField`. Then you can switch visibility in `RowDataBound`.

[Tutorial 12: Using TemplateFields in the GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx)

```
 Button btn = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("ButtonID");
 btn.Visible = i==0;
```

You can handle the `Click` event of the `Button` for your "view more"-logic.

Comment: I have autogenerated columns=true

Comment: @SandraDsouza: Then change that :)